# What is "Theoretical Computer Science"?

Tags: discussion

What exactly is "theoretical" computer science? I just saw this site as part of the Stack Exchange and wondered what this meant. I couldn't get a solid understanding by looking at the trending questions.

Comment: Have you looked at the [faq]?

Comment: Thanks for linking it! I didn't even know there was a FAQ:)

Comment: its sort of like computer science without the computers :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretical computer science is the study of the mathematical nature of computation.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_computer_science) and the references therein.

As Dave Clarke pointed out in a comment, the scope of cstheory.stackexchange.com is explained in [FAQ](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq).